# Rspec - create instance of StandardError with mocked backtrace

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

How would I create an instance of an error in rspec that contains a backtrace array of string?

I tried

```
let(:mocked_error) { StandardError.new('Mocked Standard Error') }
```

which creates the error but how can I add a backtrace?

Ideally, I would want something like but not a hash of course

```
{ :message => 'mocked error', :backtrace => ['bla', 'bla2'] }
```

Comment: Why do you want to mock an exception? What kind of logic should your test cover? How do you want to use the mocked exception in your test afterward?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

```
  specify do
    mock = Class.new(StandardError) do
      def backtrace
        ["foo", "bar"]
      end
    end

    def dostuff(exception)
      raise exception
    rescue => e
      e.backtrace
    end

    expect(dostuff(mock)).to eq(["foo", "bar"])
  end
```

It's just a matter of organizing your code in a way you can provide the exception class to be thrown, and you're good.

But the question arises: should you do it this way?

It seems like you plan to change code behavior based on what's in the backtrace. I'd suggest you add a new question with the problem you're trying to fix using the backtraces and maybe someone would be able to suggest another approach.

---

**Below is old version of the answer where I thought it was impossible with tests that allowed me to find the solution**

I don't think this is possible **if you want to raise** such an exception.

Check out the small test I made:

```rb
  specify do
    mock = instance_double(StandardError, backtrace: ["foo", "bar"])

    expect(mock.backtrace).to eq(["foo", "bar"]) # pass

    def dostuff(exception)
      raise exception
    rescue => e
      return e.backtrace
    end

    expect(dostuff(mock)).to eq(["foo", "bar"]) #fails
  end
```

The fail is:

```
       expected: ["foo", "bar"]
            got: [real_backtrace_here]
```

Why? Consider same test, altered a but (returning the caught exception instead of the backtrace):

```rb
  specify do
    mock = instance_double(StandardError, backtrace: ["foo", "bar"])

    def dostuff(exception)
      raise exception
    rescue => e
      e
    end

    expect(dostuff(mock)).to eq(mock)
  end
```

the fail message now:

```
       expected: #<InstanceDouble(StandardError) (anonymous)>
            got: #<TypeError: exception class/object expected>
```

<del>It seems like throwing or catching an exception causes a new exception object to be created.</del> (not true, see below)

It seems like you plan to change code behavior based on what's in the backtrace. I'd suggest you add a new question with the problem you're trying to fix using the backtraces and maybe someone would be able to suggest another approach.

Edit: I just realized:

```
       -#<InstanceDouble(StandardError) (anonymous)>
       +#<TypeError: exception class/object expected>
```

this is not an exception re-created, it's a new exception raised when I tried to raise a mock, and ruby does not allow that.

Answer (score -1):

How about this before your spec test

```
before do
     allow_any_instance_of(StandardError)
       .to receive(:full_message).and_return('/backtrace/to/all/files/causing/this/error','more/files/to/this/error')
    end
```